# React enable button if inputs are filled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

I am relatively new to react and javascript so my question is: 
 How in gods name do I access these two objects directly?
I tried using Object.keys without any success.

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{action: "", dest: "", }]);
const isEnabled = //how do I check if both action and dest length is > 0???

<Button disabled={!isEnabled}>Continue</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#every` to validate every object in the array.

```js
const isEnabled = inputList.every(({action, dest})=>action && dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just doing this. When one (or both) of the fields in any of the items in `inputList` has nothing in it, the condition will be `true` and the button will be disabled.

```
<Button disabled={inputList.every(({ action, dest }) => !action.length || !dest.length)}>Continue</Button>
```